# How to print all the elements from and embedded array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a 'sections' array in collections 'projects' and below is the document under that collection

```
{
    _id:"1234678",

    "sections":[
      {"ticks":[1,2,3,4,5]}
    ]
  }
```

I want to print all the values from the array "ticks" or let's say I want to retrieve all those values and put it in a variable

```
var sections=db.getCollection('projects').find({_id:"1234678"},{'sections.ticks':[]})
print(sections);
```

i tried the below query which did not work

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$arrayElemAt`, to get element at from position 0,

```
var sections = db.getCollection('projects').findOne(
    { _id: "1234678" },
    {
      "ticks": { $arrayElemAt: ["$sections.ticks", 0] }
    }
);
print(sections.ticks);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C4nZ3cAZOzj)